# Images not displaying in the center of webpage

Tags: css

I am using the following code to display two circles in the middle of the webpage. The circles do not appear in the center of the screen. Can anyone please guide me why is this happening? Thanks.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hekpr386/).

```
<div style="background-color: orange; width: 900px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <img class=" wp-image-2531 alignleft" style="clear: none;" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/meet-beneficiaries.png" alt="meet beneficiaries" width="220" height="218" /><span style="text-decoration: underline;">
    <img class="alignnone wp-image-2533" style="clear: none; margin-left: 400px;" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/meet-clients.png" alt="meet clients" width="219" height="217" /></span>
</div>
```

Comment: try this way.in div tag decrase padding-left in to 450px.then in class(alignnone wp-image-2533)remove margin-left.so you can center this circle. if u can use inspect element in browser and solve this question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hekpr386/2/ this is the way

Answer (score 3):

Remove margins and paddings on imgs and add `text-align center` on the parent,
you don't need `clear: none;`

```html
<div style="background-color: orange; width: 900px; margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;">
    <img class=" wp-image-2531 alignleft" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/meet-beneficiaries.png" alt="meet beneficiaries" width="220" height="218" /><span style="text-decoration: underline;">
    <img class="alignnone wp-image-2533" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/meet-clients.png" alt="meet clients" width="219" height="217" /></span>
</div>
```

**Important :**

Inline styles are a bad practice. You should add the style in a `.css` file.

Comment: Why `text-align: center` and `margin: auto;` ? Why not ONLY `margin: auto;` ??

Comment: Because if you remove `margin: auto` on the parent it will not be centered, `text-align: center` is to center the childrens (in this case imgs).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margins on the images and set the margin to 50% on the div.

```
<div style="background-color: orange; width: 900px; margin: 50%; padding-left:500px;">
<img class=" wp-image-2531 alignleft" style="clear: none;" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/meet-beneficiaries.png" alt="meet beneficiaries" width="220" height="218" /><span style="text-decoration: underline;">
<img class="alignnone wp-image-2533" style="clear: none;" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/meet-clients.png" alt="meet clients" width="219" height="217" /></span>
```